# Can not click cross sign of Form1 during code is running

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-4.0

1- Make Windows Form Application.

2- Put Button1 on to Form1.

3- Run following code.

```
Public Class Form1    
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)Handles Button1.Click
    For i = 1 To 10000000000
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

4- While above code is running try to click Cross sign of Form1. (See that you are not able to click Cross sign of Form1 while above code is running)

Question: Why you are not able to click Cross sign of Form1 while code is running?

How does user stop running of application without waiting it is completed?

Comment: You have the system tied up running that loop.

Comment: Run your long-running code in a separate thread so the UI thread can still receive input.

Comment: Which version of .Net framework do you use?

Comment: @Reza Aghaei http://prntscr.com/9dgr70

Comment: You are running the code in UI thread and the UI thread is too busy to be able to response, since you are using .Net 4.0 and you can't use async/await pattern you can run such codes using a thread or `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: You can [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308647) by click on checkmark near the answer, also you can vote for as many answers as you find helpful, including the accepted one, by click on up arrow near the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here

Quick (but bad) and Good

This is the quick option

```
Public Class Form1    
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)Handles Button1.Click
For i = 1 To 10000000000
   application.doevents 
   i = i + 1
Next
End Sub
End Class
```

The better option is to use a background worker or thread

```
Public Class Form1    
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)Handles Button1.Click
  Dim tThread as new threading.thread(addressof DoCount)
  tThread.start
End Sub

Private Sub DoCount()
  For i = 1 To 10000000000
   i = i + 1
  Next

End Sub
End Class
```

Either work on this simple example but when things get complex you really need to understand whats going on. You might also want to look into a Backgroundworker Here is a good place to start https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are running that loop in UI thread and the UI thread is too busy to be able to response, since you are using .Net 4.0 and you can't use async/await pattern you can execute such time-consuming operation using a thread or [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Example - Using BackgroundWorker**

Put a `BackGroundWorker` component on your form and write those codes in `DoWork` event handler. Pay attention that codes in `DoWork` will run on a different thread an you can not directly to UI and you should use `Invoke`.

```
Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    MessageBox.Show("The code immediately run")
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim sum As Integer = 0
    For index = 1 To Int32.MaxValue - 1
        sum += 1
    Next
    Me.Invoke(New Action(Sub()
                             Me.Text = ("Result: " & sum.ToString())
                         End Sub))
End Sub
```

> The `BackgroundWorker` class allows you to run an operation on a
>   separate, dedicated thread. Time-consuming operations like downloads
>   and database transactions can cause your user interface (UI) to seem
>   as though it has stopped responding while they are running. When you
>   want a responsive UI and you are faced with long delays associated
>   with such operations, the `BackgroundWorker` class provides a convenient
>   solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't click the `X` button cause your main UI thread is busy performing the big looping operation. wait and once finished you can close the form.

Else, you can re-factor your code and pull the looping information in a method and run it using a separate thread altogether. In which case your main UI thread will not be blocked.